# find recursively, but with specific sub-folder name

Tags: linux, bash

This command find all files name "log_7" recursively in current folder.

```
find . -name log_7
```

Assume many sub-folders under the current folder tree has a file with that same name "log_7":

```
./am/f1/log_7
./ke/f2/log_7
./sa/f6/log_7
..
./xx/f97/log_7
```

Is there a way to explicitly say that we only want to search for "log_7" in a folder name "f2" ? such that the result from `find` will only list only one entry:

```
./ke/f2/log_7
```

Comment: Perhaps use a regex, something like `find . -regex '.*/f2/log_7'`. This will only match if `log_7` is directly nested under `f2`

Comment: @artm you can try regex for name something like */f2/log_7

Comment: @tmcnicol on the spot, would you like to convert your comment to an answer, will accept it.

Comment: @tkhurana96 thanks to you, too; regex is beauty ;)

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: This would also do: `find ./ke/f2/ -type f -name "log_7"` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a regular expression.

```
find . -regex '.*/f2/log_7'
```

This will only match if log_7 is directly nested under f2

Answer (score 0):

There is a different way is to use xargs for same thing

```
find . -name filename | xargs grep -e refectory
```

But find with built in regex is preferable.

Comment: This would fail if the pattern to search for, is contained (as a substring) in a directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple glob should do:

```
printf '%s\n' */f2/log_7
```

If there is a possibility for more leading folders, you can use the `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
printf '%s\n' **/f2/log_7
```